# Python Flask (deployed on Heroku): ImportError: cannot import name 'secure_filename' from 'werkzeug' when deploying on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

When deploying a flask application on heroku im getting the error above. The problem on heroku is that it installs dependencies and Iam not able to overwrite them then, or?
On my local server i just went to flask_uploads.py and change the imports to:

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from werkzeug.datastructures import  FileStorage
```

and this works fine.

but when deploying the flask app to heroku, how can I change the the content of flask_uploads.py after it had been installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flask-uploads` is no longer properly maintained and has not released a fix to the updated Werkzeug API change, thus you see this error.

Just swap `flask-uploads` with `flask-reuoloaded` in your dependency list, eg requirements.txt or similar. You don't have to change your imports!

See https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded

Comment: Heyy, thx for that answer<3 it worked.... I was so desperate.

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you consider to upvote or accept my answer? Thank you